# Not able to RDP to VM

Tags: rdp, cloud

I recently migrated a VM from AWS to my GCP envrionment.

Old machine was on a abc.com domain, migrated to a VPC in GCP that has VPN tunnel to xyz.com domain.  I am able to conneect to serial port 2 with local admin creds.

I am not able to joing to the new xyz.com domain, nor am i able to RDP to the public IP through chrome RDP - accepts the creds but says machine rejects the connection.

I have forced the removed the machine from abc.com domain, confirmed remote desktop service is enabled, both through command prompt.

I have another machine in the same VPC/subnet that I spun up in gcp - and i am able to rdp/ping with on prem creds no problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So figured this out - server looks to have been the old domain's RD licensing server. Once i removed that role, and joined it to the new domain - remote access was restored